# adMob House Ad with dynamic URL address?

Tags: android, admob

Is there a way to include a house ad with URL address with parameters?  I specifically wish to track users' screen size and deviceID for statistics purpose (track new app install etc), so the URL will be like hi.php?w=720&h=1080&d=1234123412341234

Unfortunately adMob doesn't seem to be supporting this.  If not, is it the easier to modify my app in order to apply the rotation manually?  I fear this method is not getting enough flexibility though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can dynamically insert url parameters.  Your best bet is to [implement AdMob's Ad Listener](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/intermediate#adlistener), and record the relevant information on those callbacks.  Specifically, the `onReceiveAd` callback gets invoked when the ad gets served, and the `onPresentScreen` callback gets invoked when the ad gets clicked.